# Best way to use BufferedReader in Kotlin

Tags: java, bufferedreader, kotlin

So I've just started using Kotlin for Android, and converted my Android Java codes into Kotlin.

In one of the conversions, I stumbled upon a BufferedReader, which I would usually write in Java as the following:

```
String result = "";
String line = "";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(someStream);
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    result += line;
}
```

But in Kotlin, it seems that Kotlin doesn't allow me to assign values to variables in while conditions.

Currently, I've written the code as the following:

```
val reader = BufferedReader(someStream)
var line : String? = ""
while (line != null) {
    line = reader.readLine()
    result += line
}
```

which I don't find so elegant and feels prev-gen, despite using Kotlin.

What would be the best way to use BufferedReader in Kotlin?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use [`bufferedReader`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/buffered-reader.html) like so

```
val allText = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
```

Comment: An explanation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#java-7s-try-with-resources

Answer (score 24):

If you still wanted to read it line by line you could use some extension functions from std lib and do it as follows:

```
val reader = someStream.bufferedReader()
val iterator = reader.linesSequences().iterator()
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    val line = iterator.next()
    // do something with line...
}
reader.close()
```

or alternatively, using a "functional" approach:

```
val reader = someStream.bufferedReader()
reader.useLines {
    it.map { line -> // do something with line }
}
```

by using useLines, you don't need to explicitly call close on the reader, the useLines extensions function will do it for you!

Just adding those for reference.. cheers

Comment: Does `useLines` load all the lines at once? What if I am trying to read from a big file, will this use too much memory or is each line fetched as it is needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So with useLines uses a sequence which uses a lazy evaluation over a stream which is good for open file handle count: 
(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-buffered-reader/line-sequence.html).

Jetbrains suggests for large files File.forEachLine where you work with a single line at a time 
(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/for-each-line.html). But under the covers File.forEachLine still uses useLines with the same default buffer size of 8 * 1024

Answer (score 23):

you can also try using the "forEachLine" method.

```
val file = File("./folder/test.txt")
file.bufferedReader().forEachLine {
    println("value = $it")
}
```

it'll also automatically close the stream after reading the last line

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/index.html

> fun Reader.forEachLine(action: (String) -> Unit)
>   Iterates through each
>   line of this reader, calls action for each line read and closes the
>   Reader when it's completed.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use a for loop:

```
val reader = BufferedReader(someStream)
for (line in reader.lines()) {
    println(line)
}
```

While is it not as concise as the accepted answer, it will allow you to loop thru and perform some kind of logic without pumping everything into one string as shown below

```
val allText: String = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
```

Comment: Please note: You can iterate over lines using `useLines()` method which returns a lazy Sequence<String> and closes the underlying BufferedReader afterwards for you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to João Gonçalves reference to the stdlib I found that you can use [forEachLine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) to traverse the reader if needed.

Answer (score 1):

use the code like this

```
    val input = conn.inputStream
    val allText = input.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
    val result = StringBuilder()                   

    result.append(allText)
    return result.toString()

    } else {

    return "unsuccessful"

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer fails when the stream has multiple lines. This is my solution

```
val allText = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readLines().joinToString("") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use BufferReader like this :

```
val data = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
```

Comment: How does your solution any different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This solution includes the character \n after each line

```
val fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName)
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(fileInputStream))
val line = reader.buffered().use { it.readText() }
```

Comment: But the OP wanted to read all line and add them to a single string. I want something similar but as a `List<String>`. This is not answering the question.

Comment: @Martin If you want to get a list of Strings from a BufferedReader, just use readLines()